# Srsly, why use get and set on mutators?

Tags: java, mutators

Had a bit of a "is this real life moment". Why are we naming mutators with get and set prefixes:

It would just as easy and understandable to just do

myMember(myMember Member)

as setMyMember and getMyMember

Is there a historical reason why Java has this style?

Comment: Your "for-instance" lost me...I'm not sure what you intend to do with `myMember(myMember Member)`.

Comment: Could you perhaps give an example with actual code?

Comment: @Makato I think he refers as C# accessor http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa287786%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The get* and set* style of naming is specified in the JavaBeans specification, and some libraries using reflection expect this style to be used. For example, Jackson mapper can serialize a java object using the get/setters to JSON without any additional annotations; if you use a different naming style, you have to tell it where your properties are.

Note that some other programming languages use different styles. Perl libraries, for example, often use a `->someProperty()` getter and `->someProperty($newValue)` setter.

Comment: Another example, the Objective-C language (such as for iPhone development) uses `[Object propertyName]` as the getter and `[Object setPropertyName:value]` as the setter - so the standards are different for each language.

Comment: It is not just "some libraries".  The JavaBeans conventions are required by numerous frameworks ... and JEE technologies such as JSP/JSTL.